# K2 show items to selected users

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, acl, user-groups

Using K2, I want to select the users of whom the K2 items would be shown to.

How do I do this?

So far I have created user groups and put them under registered users.

Are there any components that would allow this?

Comment: What "K2 Items" are you referring to specifically e.g. K2 articles or content within an article or something else?

Comment: I want to select the users of whom the K2 items would be shown to - maybe it's my english, but I can't understand what you want to do. To me that sentence is somewhat looping in its meaning. Trying to break it out... You want to select which users with what criteria, and what k2 items and display the k2 items to who?

Comment: I want to choose which users see k2 items that I create under any clients  category

Comment: @velvetInk is this question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control access to K2 articles individually, you can do that inside that article settings in the "Access Level" field. The same setting can be applied (Access Level) to K2 categories inside each category's settings. Most likely, you've got all these set to "Public". In order to create different access levels, go to *Users > Access Levels*.

---

More reading: https://docs.joomla.org/ACL_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6#Access_Levels

Comment: @velvetInk, let me know if you have any questions setting up these permissions.